# How to check that the string is single word?

Tags: tcl

How to check that string is a single word?

Is this right way to do that?

```
set st "some string"

if { [llength $st] != 1 } {
   puts "error"
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of one word? Only letters from start to finish? If you want to include dashes (hyphens) in one word, you could check for spaces if so, but I think you need to be a bit more elaborate on what is a 'word' :)

Comment: I would like to check that the string is contain exactly one word: with any characters in it(except space).

Comment: Okay, so you will count "123%?"IHDS" as a word as well. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that a word contains only alphabet characters.

If you don't mind using some regexp, you can use this:

```
set st "some string"

if { ![regexp {^[A-Za-z]+$} $st] } {
   puts "error"
}
```

[regexp *expression* *string*] returns 0 if there is no match and 1 is there is a match.

The expression I used is `^[A-Za-z]+$` which means the string starts with a letter and can contain any number of letters and must end with a letter. If you want to include a dash inside (e.g. co-operate is one word), you add it in the character class:

`^[A-Za-z-]+$`

If you are now worried about trailing spaces, I would suggest trimming it first before passing it to the regexp:

```
set st "  some string  "

if { ![regexp {^[A-Za-z]+$} [string trim $st]] } {
   puts "error"
}
```

or if you want to directly use the regexp...

```
set st "  some string    "

if { ![regexp {^\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*$} $st] } {
   puts "error"
}
```

EDIT: If a word is considered as a string of characters except space, you can do something else: check if the string contains a space.

```
set st "some strings"

if { [regexp { } $st] } {
   puts "error"
}
```

If it finds a space, regexp will return 1.

Comment: `A-Za-z` won't match e.g. `åäö` from the swedish alphabet or `é`. I'd like to think that my last name, `Åhman`, is a word. Use `[:alpha:]` instead.

Comment: @potrzebie This regexp was prior to the 'all characters except space' confirmation and considered only (english) alphabet. The last regex is the one relevant. Sorry if I offended you not taking alphabet outside this range ^^;

Answer (score 2):

According to one possible definition, you check if a string is one word by using:

```
catch {set oneWord 0;set oneWord [expr {[llength $string] == 0}]}
```

That's the *Tcl language* definition of a word.

On the other hand, if your preferred definition is “is alphanumeric” then you have other possibilities, such as:

```
# -strict excludes the empty string (normally included for historic reasons)
set oneWord [string is alnum -strict $string]
```

Answer (score 1):

`regexp` provides a straight forward way to match a word with `\w` and `\W`. `\w` matches a word character, while `\W` matches any character *except* a word character.

```
set st "some string"
if { [regexp {\W} $st] } {
   puts "error"
}
```

However `\w` matches only `digits`, `alphabets` and `_` (in any combination). If special characters are there in your word, this will not work.

Comment: In this case, search for `\s` -- a whitespace character, usually used to split words.